# Are transverse maps in intersection theory local diffeomorphisms?

Tags: differential-topology, intersection-theory

Suppose that $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $Z$ is a submanifold of $Y$, all boundaryless. Suppose that $f$ is transverse to $Z$, so that:
$$df_x T_xX + T_{f(x)}Z = T_{f(x)}Y$$
for every $x \in f^{-1}(Z)$ and $codim(f^{-1}(Z)) = codim (Z)$. The manifolds are also "appropriate for intersection theory" in the sense that $dim(X) + dim(Z) = dim(Y)$.

**Is it true that all such $f$ are local diffeomorphisms on $x \in f^{-1}(Z)$?**

From what I understand, $df_x T_x X$ has dimension at most $dim(X)$, and the other two tangent spaces have exactly $dim(Z)$ and $dim(Y)$ respectively. Given the condition on dimensions, it seems that we must have $df_x T_x X$ be of dimension $dim(X)$, so that $df_x$ is a full-rank map. Thus, $df_x$ must be an isomorphism, and from the inverse function theorem, $f$ must be a local diffeomorphism at $x$.

I'm hoping that someone could confirm this, or point out any errors in the reasoning if untrue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general dimensions a standard transversality result (It is just analysis and can be found in Hirsch or Bröcker Jänich) gives you that $im(f)\cap Z$ is a smooth submanifold of dimension $dimX+dimZ - dim Y$, i.e. the pullback $M$ of the maps $f$ and the inclusion of $Z$ stays in category:

$$
\begin{array}{c}
M& \hookrightarrow &Z\\
\downarrow &&\downarrow\\
X & \to &Y
\end{array}
$$

So we have that $X$ restricted to $f^{-1}Z=M \subset X$ is an embedding, i.e. a diffeomorphism onto its image $M\hookrightarrow Y$.

In the case that we consider complementary dimensions, the intersection will be 0-dimensional, i.e. a bunch of points. In this case it just means, that the points, will be full rank points of $f$ as you noticed correctly, since otherwise by linear algebra we wouldn't add up to the right dimension.

But it does *not* mean that it is an isomorphism, since we still could have $dimX < dim Y$ or equivalently $dimZ\neq 0$!

Comment: Before I approve this answer, I'd like two things: 1) Please define your notation; I'm not entirely clear what $M$ even is. 2) A citation to the "fundamental transversality result" would be very helpful!

Comment: I think I also misread the question so I added a note in the end. I will also edit it accordingly.